# How use multiple conditions in If condition in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to use multiple `or` conditions in `If` condition in XSLT.

The code I used:

```
<xsl:if test="$var eq ('xxx','yyy','zzz','mmm')">
```

When I used the above code I am getting error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare sequences use the `=` operator, not `eq`. So assuming you use an XSLT 2 or processor your syntax using `$var = ('xxx','yyy','zzz','mmm')` should work. With an XSLT 1 processor the right hand side expression constructing a string sequence is not supported at all as the data types there are primitive values and node-sets and (in XSLT) result tree fragments but not sequences of strings or types in general.